# Ascii characters more reliable in html?

Tags: html

Im making a webpage. In the html is it better to use ascii characters? The following look the same for me when I test in different browsers but is the first one better practice?

```
Opening &#45;

Opening -
```

Comment: are you using any other languages like PHP or javascript?

Comment: What character set? Btw, '-' is an ASCII character.

Comment: Writing a Chinese web site with plain US-ASCII characters is an exercise of masochism. Look at the source code of all major sites: they all use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use literals like `-` over escaped `&#45` entities, and it is also encouraged for readability. Only characters you have to escape are the so called "unsafe entities" (like `<` and `>` are, as they can mark a new tag and therefore are ambigous to the browser.

If you declare the document encoding as UTF-8, then you can insert any character (also non ASCII, like letters from foreign alphabets or accented letters) which will not violate markup syntax.

Only reason to keep `&...` characters is compatibility with ancient browser not recognizing UTF-8.

Comment: No, no, I'm saying the opposite! Sorry for the misunderstanding, clarifying.

Comment: Ah, alright. It felt weird, given that the rest of the answer was pretty reasonable :)